Metric under conformal transformation
I have a question regarding the conformal factor $\Omega(x)$ when dealing with a conformal transformation. We know that under a change of coordinates $x\rightarrow x^{'}=x^{'}(x)$ our metric changes as
\begin{equation}
g_{\mu\nu}(x)\rightarrow g^{'}_{\mu\nu}(x)=\frac{\partial x^{\alpha}}{\partial x^{'\mu}}\frac{\partial x^{\beta}}{\partial x^{'\nu}}g_{\alpha\beta}(x)
\end{equation}
Now when we scale our coordinates $x'=\lambda x$ this gives us
\begin{equation}
g^{'}_{\mu\nu}(x)=\frac{1}{\lambda^{2}}g_{\mu\nu}(x)
\end{equation}
My question is, is my conformal factor $\Omega(x)=\frac{1}{\lambda}$ which gives $g^{'}_{\mu\nu}(x)=\Omega(x)^{2}g_{\mu\nu}(x)$? or is it $\Omega(x)=\lambda$ which gives instead $g^{'}_{\mu\nu}(x)=\Omega^{-2}(x)g_{\mu\nu}(x)$? I'm confused given that in the lectures by Thomas Hartman in Black holes and Quantum information (page ~11/12 of his handwritten notes which I linked) he writes $g^{'}_{\mu\nu}(x)=\Omega^{-2}(x)g_{\mu\nu}(x)$. Why are we allowed to express it as $g^{'}_{\mu\nu}(x)=\Omega^{-2}(x)g_{\mu\nu}(x)$? Doesn't a conformal transformation scale the metric as $g^{'}_{\mu\nu}(x)=\Omega^{2}(x)g_{\mu\nu}(x)$? Similarly in Anthony Zee Group theory in a Nutshell for physicist on page 516 for a scale transformation he arrives that our metric changes as
\begin{equation}
g^{'}_{\mu\nu}(x)=\lambda^{2}g_{\mu\nu}(x)
\end{equation}
using the first formula provided at the top which is different than what I derived. I would appreciate some clarification on this as it seems there an important detail I am missing.
